# how set asp.net core startup project using command line in Vs code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-2.0

I have multiple projects in my workspace. how I can set a startup project using the command line.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? The single `launch.json`s in each project should already have all the startup configurations, how were you planning to launch your selected project?

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in way to set the startup project in a *persistent* manner, but you can specify the project to run when using `dotnet run` with the `--project` [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run#options):

```
dotnet run --project /path/to/project
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing startup project in VS Code, you should open launch.json file from Explorer window and edit "program" and "cwd" attributes.